# Text scaling and positioning in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working with libgdx. I need to scale and position text. Let's say I want to draw X that is 30 pixels hight and I want it to be in the middle of the screen. I want to draw more of those in diffrent locations and with different scales.

Is there any way how could I achieve that? I can't find the solution anywhere. I dont want to create more BitmapFonts if possible.

Comment: You can create a Label actor, which should be scalable. Or you can draw text into frame buffer using always the same bitmap font, and then scale fbo texture and draw it with sprite batch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle all platforms (android, html, ios, desktop) you need to use several BitmapFonts in order to avoid ugly scaling. Otherwise, if you don't need to deploy to HTML, you can use the gdx-freetype extension (see here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype).

Assuming you go with BitmapFont, you can simply use code similar to this to center your text:

```
        String text = "Your text here!";
        TextBounds bounds = font.getBounds(text);
        font.draw(batch, text, (width - bounds.width) / 2.0f, (height - bounds.height) / 2.0f);
```

For scaling, you can set the scale in font.draw, but you probably want several BitmapFont of various sizes to avoid ugly artifacts.